# Karma: proj4 is not a function

Tags: angular, teamcity, karma-runner, angular-cli, proj4js

Really strange one. I have built an angular app with TeamCity and am trying to run karma tests as a build task:

```
ng test
```

2 of the tests failed complaining about a missing dependency which happens to be `proj4`.

Stepping through the failed test, this is really wierd.

The call to proj4 is by function (works locally in the app and tests):

```
const coords = proj4(sourceProjection, targetProjection, point.toArray());
```

but on build server yields `proj4 is not a function`, but proj4 does exists however it is behind a property called "default", so that in the debugger

```
proj4.default(sourceProjection, targetProjection, point.toArray());
```

works.

I mean wtf!? Who or what is supplementing that `.default` property. Ruddy build systems!

I have double checked the angular-cli, npm, node etc are all the same versions.

FWIW proj4 is a node_module included in the app via the `angular-cli.json`'s script property.

Comment: Hi. I have the same issue on my real code (not testing). have you figure it out?

Comment: I have a similar problem, after I webpack it's only accessible via the "default" attribute.  Not sure what's going on here, but thanks for asking the question since it helped me solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing with Parcel bundler. As you stated, can be fixed by eg. replacing

`const proj4 = require("proj4")` with

`const proj4 = require("proj4").default`